# ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: not installing on Android api level 23

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gruntjs

I am currently working on developing hybrid app using ionic.
At this moment everything works fine as expected when i try to run it in browser using **ionic run** and **grunt serve**.

But when i try to install app on mobile it gives me error like [image: error installing on mobile] 
Now this seems like issue of minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.
Although i am sharing my [config.xml](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23115845/) so you can get clear idea.

I am having big trouble solving this problem. If you guys can point me in the right direction, that would be great help.

NOTE: please ask me if you need any extra information about anything.

SDK information [image: SDK platform of api 21,23]

Comment: Did you have already installed the app on your device? Try to delete from device and try again

Comment: yes, but after that i uninstalled that. i installed with 'grunt run:android' with usb debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in config.xml i have inserted two line that was wrong.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/> and <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
```

that was wrong, i created new ionic sample project and in that project opened config.xml and i saw that there was only one line that was

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
```

so i copied that and put in my config.xml file then i removed android platform and added android platform again.

then i try to run in massmalow,lollipop and all other device. that works like charm.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 10):

You just need remove the old version of your app on device and reinstall again.

**remember** :

1. Uninstall the program.
2. Disable and enable USB debugging, in turn.
3. Run "Cordova run Android" command.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you forget changing package name will conflict with the old app if still was installed on your device

But as first you can try to :

- ***Disable and enable USB debugging, in turn.***

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the launcher activity on Manifest File

As for my case, I added the following inside the application tag;

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

run again it will work. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qWTR.png)some times when you change the branches in android it will give this issue.